# Execute command prompt file (.cmd) from within a PowerShell script?

Tags: script, powershell

What command do I need to put in a .ps1 file to execute `setup.cmd` and make it a forced install?

I've tried to execute this command in powershell and its working:

`PS C:\> c:\setup.cmd install-setupforced`

I would like to know how I can use this command inside a .ps1 script.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking how to run commands from a Powershell script... You probably wan to use the Invoke-Command cmdlet. Your script would look something like this:

```
Invoke-Command setup.cmd -ArgumentList install-setupforced
```

That may work. Please be sure to check out `help Invoke-Command` in Powershell.

Comment: 'Invoke-Command C:\setup.cmd -ArgumentList install-setupforced' i try this but it doesn't work. Error message is "Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters."

Comment: Do you need to cast your argument to an array?  E.g. @("install-setupforced").  From `Get-Help Invoke-Command` in PowerShell 3.0: "**Invoke-Command** [[-Session] <PSSession[]>] **[-FilePath] <string>** [-ThrottleLimit <int>] [-AsJob] [-HideComputerName] [-JobName <string>] [-InputObject <psobject>] **[-ArgumentList <Object[]>]**  [<CommonParameters>]"